# scroll inner scroll bar in a website using rselenium r

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrollbar, rselenium

I have this website (https://www.sofascore.com/pt/torneio/futebol/brazil/brasileiro-serie-a/325) that I want to get some stats from games by round. There is 38 rounds and the base just shows the first 11. For me to get the rest of the rounds I have to scroll this inner scroll bar but I don't know how to do it.

I use the package RSelenium in R.

[image: here's the image]

Comment: If you need help, you should provide the code. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck

Comment: @ConorNeilson I didn't try anything because I don't know how to work with this scroll bar. I know that when the bar moves, the style code "top: 0px;" changes. I don't know if there's a way that I can control the scroll bar just by changing this part to something like "top: 100px;", for example. Or if there's any other way to move the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code (so far)...
After this, I don't know what to do...

```
require(RSelenium)

click <- function(xpath){
    webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = xpath)
    webElem$clickElement()
}

driver <- rsDriver(port = 5799L, browser = c('chrome'), chromever = "88.0.4324.96")

url = 'https://www.sofascore.com/pt/torneio/futebol/brazil/brasileiro-serie-a/325'

remDr <- driver[['client']]
remDr$navigate(url) #link
Sys.sleep(1)

# games by round
click('//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/a[2]')

# round options
click('//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')
```